# NavigationService.Navigate() is Not Working After InApp Product Purchase Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I am Using the Following Code to Do the Inapp Purchase in My App.

```
            if (!CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[product.ProductID].IsActive)
            {
                var receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(product.ProductID, true);
            }
            if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[product.ProductID].IsActive)
            {
                 //Update the Purchase into  the Local Settings
                MessageBox.Show("Inapp product bought successfully", "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                //Because the Purchase is successful move to a diffferent page 
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));        
            }
            else
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Inapp purchase Failed", "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
```

Everything is Working Perfectly Fine Related to the Inapp Purchase but After the Purchase is successful navigate to a page is not happening. Its just staying in the Same Page on which the Purchase was initiated.

Comment: double check with your UriKind

Comment: This could be because the in-app purchase is still being awaited when the if statement is being executed and the condition where your app should Navigate to the MainPage is not being executed because the purchase has not been completed and therefore - License.IsActive is returning false? Try putting a breakpoint on the if condition and check if conditions is being stepped into.